# why does my threading doesn't want to decrypt a byte while having a tkinter interface

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyserial

I have a tkinter interface to manage a project with an arduino mega, and i want my program to communicate with the arduino. actually i can send data and have a response without problem. but when i create a thread to check if a new info has been sent by the arduino it doesn't work and doesn't want to decode.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.font import *
import schedule

import chardet
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event,Condition
import sys, time
from random import randint
import serial,serial.tools.list_ports


state=None
ready=False

root = Tk()


def find_USB_device(USB_DEV_NAME=None):
    myports = [tuple(p) for p in list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())]
    #print(myports)
    usb_port_list = [p[0] for p in myports]
    usb_device_list = [p[1] for p in myports]
    #print(usb_device_list)

    if USB_DEV_NAME is None:
        return myports
    else:
        USB_DEV_NAME=str(USB_DEV_NAME).replace("'","").replace("b","")
        for device in usb_device_list:
            print("{} -> {}".format(USB_DEV_NAME,device))
            print(USB_DEV_NAME in device)
            if USB_DEV_NAME in device:
                print(device)
                usb_id = device[device.index("COM"):device.index("COM")+4]
            
                print("{} port is {}".format(USB_DEV_NAME,usb_id))
                return usb_id
   
def show_menu(event):
    menu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_command(label="fermer",accelerator="CTRL+E", command=root.destroy)
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

def screen_dim():
    global screen_height, screen_width
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    taille=str(int(screen_width/1.5)) +"x"+str(screen_height)
    return taille


root.title("Escape game management")
root.geometry(screen_dim())




frame_command=Frame(root, padding=10, height=800 ,style='external.TFrame')
frame_connexion = Frame(frame_command)
frame_connexion_2= Frame(frame_command)


com_li=[p[0] for p in find_USB_device()]
combobox =Combobox(frame_connexion, values=com_li)
if len(com_li)>0:  combobox.set(com_li[0]) 
else: print("aucune carte branché")

command_var=StringVar()
command_entry = Entry(frame_connexion_2,textvariable = command_var, font=("Gotham",10))

consol_text = Text(frame_command, height = 50, width=60, font=("Gotham",10))


def readData():
    answer=""
    ij=0
    while state.readable() and answer=="" and ij<2:
        ij= ij+1
        decoded_readline=state.readline().decode("utf-8") 
        if not(decoded_readline==""):
            answer += decoded_readline
    return answer 
def updateData():
    if ready:
        try:
            answer=readData()
        except:
            answer=""
        if answer!="":
            consol_text.insert(END,("\n>"+answer))


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(1):
            updateData()


stopFlag = Event()
thread = MyThread(stopFlag)

def connect_serial():
    global ser
    global state
    global ready
    consol_text.insert(END,(">> tentative de connexion à %s ..." % combobox.get()))
    state=serial.Serial(combobox.get(), 115200, timeout=None)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    answer=readData()
    if answer!="":
        consol_text.insert(END,("\n>> Connecté!\n"+answer))
        ready=True
        thread.start()






def sendData():
    global state
    name=command_var.get()
    if ready:
        if state.isOpen():
            if name != "":
                state.write(name.encode())
                answer=readData()
                command_var.set("")
                consol_text.insert(END,(answer))
        

btn1 = Button(frame_connexion, text = 'connect',style = 'W.TButton', command =lambda: connect_serial())
btn2 = Button(frame_connexion_2, text = 'send',style = 'W.TButton', command =lambda: sendData())



style = Style()
style.configure('TFrame', height=root.winfo_screenheight()-40)
style.configure('external.TFrame', background="#DDDDDD")

root.bind("<Button-3>", show_menu)
root.bind('<Control-e>', lambda e: root.destroy())
root.bind_all('<Control-w>', lambda e: sendData())

frame_command.grid(column=0, row=0,)
frame_connexion.pack(side=TOP)
frame_connexion_2.pack(side=TOP)
command_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
btn2.pack(side=RIGHT)
combobox.pack(side = LEFT)
btn1.pack(side=RIGHT)
consol_text.pack(side = BOTTOM)



root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
stopFlag.set()
```

here is my control panel
and i wanted the line of code my arduino sent to be show just under
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6edF.png)

actually i have made a test without the tkinter interface like this :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.font import *
import schedule

import chardet
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event,Condition
import sys, time
from random import randint
import serial,serial.tools.list_ports


state=None
ready=False

def find_USB_device(USB_DEV_NAME=None):
    myports = [tuple(p) for p in list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())]
    #print(myports)
    usb_port_list = [p[0] for p in myports]
    usb_device_list = [p[1] for p in myports]
    #print(usb_device_list)

    if USB_DEV_NAME is None:
        return myports
    else:
        USB_DEV_NAME=str(USB_DEV_NAME).replace("'","").replace("b","")
        for device in usb_device_list:
            print("{} -> {}".format(USB_DEV_NAME,device))
            print(USB_DEV_NAME in device)
            if USB_DEV_NAME in device:
                print(device)
                usb_id = device[device.index("COM"):device.index("COM")+4]
            
                print("{} port is {}".format(USB_DEV_NAME,usb_id))
                return usb_id
            
com_li=[p[0] for p in find_USB_device()]
usb_port=com_li[0]

def readData():
    answer=""
    ij=0
    while state.readable() and answer=="" and ij<2:
        ij= ij+1
        decoded_readline=state.readline().decode("utf-8") 
        if not(decoded_readline==""):
            answer += decoded_readline
    return answer 

def updateData():
    if ready:
        try:
            answer=readData()
        except:
            answer=""
        if answer!="":
            print("\n>"+answer)

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(1):
            updateData()


stopFlag = Event()
thread = MyThread(stopFlag)

def connect_serial():
    global ser
    global state
    global ready
    print((">> tentative de connexion à %s ..." % usb_port))
    state=serial.Serial(usb_port, 115200, timeout=None)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    answer=readData()
    if answer!="":
        print(("\n>> Connecté!\n"+answer))
        ready=True
        thread.start()
        #state.register_event_handler(state.readable(), updateData)
'''        updater = Thread(target=updateData, args=())
        updater.start()'''





def sendData():
    global state
    name="begin"
    if ready:
        if state.isOpen():
            if name != "":
                state.write(name.encode())
                answer=readData()
                print((answer))
        




connect_serial()
sendData()
```

and here my threading worked i don't understand why and how i can fix that